# How to check whether a student faced disciplinary action

Tags: disciplinary-action

I reported a fellow classmate's verbal abuse to my professor and an associate dean at my school in a previous semester. I showed proof as I was reporting the incident. Their response to me was merely that his behavior was "very unprofessional" and that was it. They never told me if and how they were going to proceed with this student's behavior.

Is there a way for me to check if the student faced any disciplinary action or not without asking the folks that I spoke with? I have a feeling that no disciplinary action was ever taken, and this was pathetically in a master's program.

Comment: What country are you in?  In some educational or legal systems, a student's disciplinary record is confidential and may not be disclosed to anyone, not even their accuser, without the student's consent.

Answer (score 3):

No, you probably cannot find out what the outcome was.  Here in the US (and perhaps elsewhere) disciplinary actions are confidential.

Comment: Confidential _by law_ actually.

Comment: FERPA prohibits this kind of disclosure

Answer (score 0):

If your university has a student welfare center or an ombudsman, they’ll be the right address.

Sorry this happened...